# Turning on screen programmatically

Tags: android, screen, locking

I would like to unlock screen and switching it on to show a popup on an event trigger. I am able to unlock the screen using

```
newKeyguardLock = km.newKeyguardLock(HANDSFREE);
newKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

on `KeyGuardService` but I cannot turn on the screen. I am using

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, HANDSFREE);
wl.acquire();
```

but with no success. The screen still remains off.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Note from author:** I wrote this back in 2012.  I don't know if it works anymore. Be sure to check out the other more recent answers.

---

Amir's answer got me close, but you need the `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` flag at least (Building against Android 2.3.3).

```
WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
     PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
screenLock.acquire();

//later
screenLock.release();
```

Answer (score 11):

**This is very popular question but the accepted answer now is outdated**.

Below is latest way to **Turn On Screen** OR wake up your device screen from an activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
} else {
    final Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Use [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON) but FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON flag has been deprecated in `API level 27` so you can use [Activity.setTurnScreenOn(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTurnScreenOn(boolean)) from `API level 27` onward.

Comment: I provided Kotlin solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76755187/10233647

Answer (score 3):

In your main activity's OnCreate() write following code:

```
((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG").acquire();
```

It causes the device to wake up.

Do not forget disableKeyguard() to unlock the device...

Answer (score 1):

undefined's answer with NullPointer check and set timeout :

```
private void turnOnScreen() {
    PowerManager.WakeLock screenLock = null;
    if ((getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)) != null) {
        screenLock = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        screenLock.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/);


        screenLock.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock  wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "appname::WakeLock");

    //acquire will turn on the display
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

make sure to set permission in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**2023 working Kotlin version**

I needed to modify this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979446/10233647 a little bit, but finally managed to make it work!

Try simply:

```
val window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
```

This really wakes the screen, when it's locked!