# Switch on screen and let default display timeout take over?

Tags: android, screen, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I'd like to switch on the screen from a service and immediately let the default system timeout take over (i.e. not hold a wakelock for a specific time, but just hand over control to the system). I've tried `WakeLock.acquire()` followed immediately by `WakeLock.release()` (with a `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`), but that doesn't even switch on the screen at all. Is there any way to achieve this from a `Service` (short of launching a new  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`-dummy-activity)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222999/1952459) is what you are looking for. You need to use

```
PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks so much :)!! I've spent days trying to figure out how I could achieve this.