# Calling button.performClick() automatically just after activity is fully loaded?

Tags: android, android-activity

I start an activity from a background service which unlocks the phone and starts an activity. What I want to achieve is to go to home screen just after the activity is loaded. I created a button on the activity that I go to just after unlocking and on its OnClick method I used:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Now, I need to call buttonName.performClick() somewhere but where? I tried onResume and onPause so far, but no luck. How or where can I make sure the activity is fully loaded?

```
//What I do on my Service to start Activity that unlocks the phone
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, StartStopActivity.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

This is the activity class:

```
    public class StartStopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_stop);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        Button returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
        });
        //returnButton.performClick();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


    }
}
```

Comment: in the end of onCreate add the function directly which you have called inside click of that button.

Comment: not working on onCreate, it does return to the home screen and unlocks the phone but for some reason it doesn't turn the screen on.

Comment: Show your code so that I can give you a good answer accordingly

Comment: It should work, please post your code.

Comment: I just added the codes.

Comment: @KaanDemirel :: add moveTaskToBack(true); in the end of the onCreate() it will call automatically when that activity is loaded.

Comment: The problem is, it's actually working and returns to home screen but I cannot see it because screen won't turn on when I call at the end of onCreate.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10222999/6127411

Comment: performClick works fine but unlock doesn't work.

Comment: @P.Rai Unlock works if I don't do anything. It opens up the activity.

Comment: @jankigadhiya Worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private PowerManager mPowerManager;
 private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

 public void turnOnScreen(){
     // turn on screen
     Log.v("ProximityActivity", "ON!");
     mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
     mWakeLock.acquire();
}

 @TargetApi(21) //Suppress lint error for PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK
 public void turnOffScreen(){
     // turn off screen
     Log.v("ProximityActivity", "OFF!");
     mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
     mWakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult just turn the screen on and set you parameters to keep the screen on if you want

Answer (score 0):

**OnClick** method will only be called when you `click` on a view. You just can't invoke it without clicking on anything.

Just copy the code that you have inside your `onclick` method and put in inside your `oncreate().` or anywhere where you want that piece of code to be executed.

It will not be `automatically called` if you don't actually click on that view to which you have set the click listener.

Change your code like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_stop);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Comment: If I call moveTaskToBack there, screen is not turning on.