# Android push notifications with Firebase not turning on device screen

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification

I am trying to get a similar behavior with remote push notifications on the Android version of my app as I have in my iOS version. In iOS, when a notification arrives it shows a heads up message regardless of the state of the app or the device (more or less...) If the app is in the foreground, background, or screen turned off - it always shows a message. But in Android, I haven't been able to find a solution that works when the device screen is turned off. So my question is, how can I make a remote notification turn on the screen and show the notification as a heads up message?

I have the following implementation of the `FirebaseMessagingService`.

```kotlin
class NotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {


    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        remoteMessage.data.let {
            it["body"]?.let { body -> sendNotification(body) }
        }

    }

    private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {
        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val requestCode = 0
        val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            requestCode,
            fullScreenIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "My Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,
            )
            channel.description = "Notifications."
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(200, 200, 200, 200, 200)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)

        val notificationId = 0
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

I have these permissions in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
```

As well as the messaging service.

```
<service
    android:name=".NotificationService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

This works fine and shows a heads-up message when the app is in the foreground or background, but not on a locked / turned off screen.
I have seen solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891337/turning-on-screen-programmatically).

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
} else {
    final Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

But since I am passing the `fullScreenIntent` directly to the `notificationBuilder`, I'm not sure where to add this code (Kotlin equivalent of course). It seems that it should belong to the specific `Activity` of the heads-up message. But how can I access that?

Alternatively, I guess I could build a custom notification with it's own `Activity`, but then I'm not sure how to pass the data from the notification to it. And I would rather use the default notification layout than have to make a custom one.

I hope there is a more straightforward way of solving this, preferably a simple method on the builder. I noticed that there is a `setPublicVersion()` method, but I'm not sure if this is applicable here or how I would implement this.

Any suggestions / solutions are most welcome!
Cheers!